# Android difference between “setSelected()” and "setChecked()

Tags: java, android, radio-button, radio-group

I have a `RadioGroup` which contains only 2 `RadioButton`, I want to set checked state for the first `RadioButton` but failed with `typeRadioGroup.getChildAt(0).setSelected(true)`. However, `((RadioButton) typeRadioGroup.getChildAt(0)).setChecked(true)` works, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SetSelected()** is View Property. We can extend this for any View in Android.

For **setSelected()**

```
public void setSelected (boolean selected)
```

Changes the selection state of this view. A view can be selected or not. the selected view is the view that is highlighted

While **setChecked()** is RadioGroup Property. Which changes checked and unchecked state of RadioButton

Answer (score 0):

> If you need to change the radio button state yourself, use the `setChecked(boolean)` or `toggle()` method.

`setChecked(boolean)` sets the intrinsic boolean dataMember associated with your view object and `setSelected(boolean)` sets the UI associated with your view object.